# flutter web app don't response to screen resizing

Tags: flutter, web, web-applications, screen

I have a phone app which works fine in different screen sizes. I made a web version of that app, when I run it on chrome browser it works and looks good, however, if I change the screen size while the app still running, there is a RenderFlex overflowed error, when I click hot restart the app resizing itself to the new screen size and the error gone. I used mediaQuery for sizing.

my question is how can I make my web app resizing itself when the browser screen zoom-in or zoom-out?

Comment: both hot restart and hot reload fixed the error and the app resized itself correctly

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
return LayoutBuilder(
  builder: (context, constraints){
    return YourView();
  },
);
```

to listen to screen size updates

Comment: Thank you for your help. It's hard to me to use layoutbuilder, because I already defined the initial height and width at the beginning and use them everywhere as a scaling sizes. I found another alternative solution for this issue. I wrap my main widget with a sizedbox that has the initial height and width values, and I wrap that sizedbox with FittedBox widget which solve the problem for me.